# C# Linq - как найти в таблице все минимальные элементы?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть два массива. В одном список издательств с полями (publishId, publishName), во втором книги, с полями (bookName, publishId, price).
Нужно при помощи Linq запроса вывести список самых дешёвых книг каждого издательства.

Возможно ли это сделать одним запросом? Или лучше сперва собрать всё в один массив и уже выбирать из него? Как тогда из такого массива выбрать сразу все минимальные цены для каждого издательства?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ну если я правильно понимаю, всё-равно когда название издательства джойнить - до groupby или после. Просто в одном случае группировка будет по имени издательства и id, а в другом только по id.

Comment: Собрать всё в принципе наверное можно вот так, но как потом отобрать только самые дешёвые книги каждого издательства?  

var tmp = from p in publishs  
                 from b in books  
                 where p.IdPublish == b.IdPublish  
                 select new  
                 {  
                     Publish = p.publishName,  
                     BookTitle = b.bookName,  
                     Price = b.Price 
                   };

Comment: Скажу так... Вам для чего? Если учеба - делайте всего как можно больше (в меру, конечно), разбивайте все на запросы, отдельные методы и прочее, это вам будет проще для понимания. Если это уже полноценный проект, то там уже думайте об уменьшении всего, и то, длинный LINQ не есть хорошо, плохо читается. А так, ваш весь запрос сводится, по сути, к простому `var result = books.GroupBy(x => x.PublishId).Select(x => (Publisher: publishers.Find(p => p.Id == x.Key), MinPriceBook: x.MinBy(x => x.Price)));`, где сначала группируем по id, а затем просто составляем нужный нам вид.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Да, это именно то что нужно. Правда пришлось массив издательств в List преобразовать. Наверное как-то можно без этого будет обойтись через лямбды, но суть понятна. Как минимум так подойдёт, как максимум придумаю схожее решение. Ещё раз огромное спасибо вам.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ 'books.GroupBy(x => x.PublishId).Select(x => (Publisher: publishers.Find(p => p.Id == x.Key), MinPriceBook: x.MinBy(x => x.Price)))' выдаёт только одну книгу с минимальной ценой, а их может быть несколько

Comment: @rotabor Самая дешевая - это одна конкретная книга, если у них цены одинаковые, то да, только я не думаю, что автору вопроса нужно это. Не, если нужно, то дополняем `MinBy`, где перед ним сначала группируем по цене, а потом уже `MinBy` по группе, забирая группу целиком с конкретной, минимальной ценой. Тут уже скажем так, тонкие настройки, который каждый сам под себя уже должен делать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ "Самая дешевая - это одна конкретная книга" - это ошибочный постулат. Никогда не следует так думать.

Comment: @rotabor Повторю, для тестовых задач, где вам преподаватель дает просто "найди мне самую дешевую книгу" это всегда работает и будет работать, ибо сама задача к этому сводится, там нету "КНИГИ", там есть "КНИГА", где у цены не повторяются. Но на продакшене, в реальном проекте, да, конечно так не стоит думать, но все зависит от ситуаций, например у меня есть проект, где раз в 30 мин идет итерация, где за одну итерацию мне надо найти самую минимальную вещь, одну, мне без разницы какая там будет, хоть их 10 минимальных на самом деле, мне нужна всего одна, ну и что, буду доставать все 10 сразу?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ В вопросе "Нужно при помощи Linq запроса вывести список самых дешёвых книг каждого издательства" слово книга употреблено во множественном числе. Это если быть формалистом.

Comment: @rotabor Вы ведь понимаете, что спорите сейчас из-за пустяка, да?) Вот вы мне кидаете претензии, мод неправильно ради чего? Чтоб я признал что-то? Или что? Я вам уже сказал свой ход мысли, я уже сказал, что мой вариант можно изменить под множественный результат элементарно, что еще хотите от меня услышать, м? Не нам с вами решать, что там нужно автору, не нам с вами решать, что правильно, а лишь автору, который как видите пропал. И да, если вы не заметили, от меня нету ответов, он меня лишь комментарий, который подталкивает к решению, не более. Так что, надеюсь закрыли это вопрос?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а тут такое бывает, что вопрос бесследно исчезает вместе с ответом?

Comment: @rotabor Если на вопрос был дан ответ, его приняли, или он имеет положительные голоса, то автор не может сам удалить вопрос, в случае если негатив или вообще нет голосов - тут честно, не знаю. Также вопрос может быть закрыт другими участниками, если те посчитают его неприемлемым для сайта по одной из "закрывашек". Только в этом случае, вопрос не удаляется, по крайней мере пока, если везде минуса и вопрос закрыт, то его удалит потом сама система. Ну и еще не забывайте про модераторы, они тоже могут закрыть. Так что да, иногда пропадают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заковыка здесь в том, что сначала нужно для каждого издательства найти минимальную цену (считаем это как самое дешёвое, хотя может быть и какая-то граница задана), а потом уже вывести все книги (их может быть больше одной для издательства), которые имеют минимальную цену для каждого издательства. Это можно сделать и в одном запросе (даже лучше). Надеюсь, это поможет создать запрос.

**Дополнено.**

Приходится добавлять код, а то предлагают неправильные решения.

```
var publishers = new List<Publisher> { new Publisher(1, "O`Reilly"), new Publisher(2, "Microsoft Press") };
var books = new List<Book> { new Book("C++", 1, 10.5), new Book("Python", 1, 12), new Book("Ruby", 1, 10.5), new Book("Java", 1, 17)
    , new Book("C#", 2, 11), new Book("F#", 2, 15), new Book("VB", 2, 12) };
Console.WriteLine("Wrong result:");
var result = books.GroupBy(x => x.publishId)
    .Select(x => (Publisher: publishers.Find(p => p.publishId == x.Key).publishName, MinPriceBook: x.MinBy(x => x.price).bookName));
foreach (var res in result) Console.WriteLine($"{res.Publisher} {res.MinPriceBook}");
Console.WriteLine("\r\nCorrect result:");
var results = books.Where(x => x.price == books.Where(w => w.publishId == x.publishId).Min(m => m.price))
    .Select(x => (Publisher: publishers.Find(p => p.publishId == x.publishId).publishName, MinPriceBook: x.bookName));
foreach (var res in results) Console.WriteLine($"{res.Publisher} {res.MinPriceBook}");
struct Publisher
{
    int _publishId; string _publishName;
    public Publisher(int i, string s) { _publishId = i; _publishName = s; }
    public int publishId { get { return _publishId; } }
    public string publishName { get { return _publishName; } }
}
struct Book
{
    string _bookName; int _publishId; double _price;
    public Book(string s, int i, double p) { _bookName = s; _publishId = i; _price = p; }
    public string bookName { get { return _bookName; } }
    public int publishId { get { return _publishId; } }
    public double price { get { return _price; } }
}
```

Результат:

Wrong result:

O`Reilly C++

Microsoft Press C#

Correct result:

O`Reilly C++

O`Reilly Ruby

Microsoft Press C#